# Changing colour based on number in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I've got a number located in `result.score`. Essentially, if the following calculation `{Math.round((result.score / 89).toFixed(2) * 100)}` is 0 -> 24 I would like to make the `pathColor:` in `CircularProgressbar` red, if 25 -> 50 I would like to make it yellow and if it's 51 -> 100 I would like to make it green. What is the easiest way to do this?

```
const Graph = () => (
  <div class="score">
    {results.length > 0 && (
      <div>
        {results.map((result) => (
          <CircularProgressbar
            value={result.score}
            text={`${Math.round((result.score / 89).toFixed(2) * 100)}%`}
            styles={buildStyles({
              pathColor: "#2bad60",
              textColor: "#2bad60",
              trailColor: "#0b0c18",
              backgroundColor: "#3e98c7",
            })}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    )}
  </div>
);
```

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment. I just want to change the `pathColor: #2bad60` based on the result from Math.round((result.score / 89).toFixed(2) * 100). Not sure what other information is required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can declare this calculation in a new constant and then use the following:

```
const scoreVar = Math.round((result.score / 89).toFixed(2) * 100)

pathColor: scoreVar <= 24 ? "orange" : (scoreVar <= 50 ? "yellow" : "green"),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make some class "red", "yellow", "green" and add one of them to your progress bar depending on the value.

Comment: I'm quite new to React, could you show me how this could be done? Thanks

Comment: I don't know about React neither but accord to the progress bar I found here : https://codepen.io/JimmyMultani/pen/mmMqYb
you can check the value, add a class depending on it and set the stroke value in css, but it may not be the best way in React